# Improving a simple function using threading

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I have written a simple function with the following code that calculates the minimum number from a one-dimensional array:

```
uint32_t get_minimum(const uint32_t* matrix) {
    int min = 0;
    min = matrix[0];


    for (ssize_t i = 0; i < g_elements; i++){
      if (min > matrix[i]){
        min = matrix[i];
      }
    }

    return min;
}
```

However, I wanted to improve the performance of this function and was advised using threads so I have modified it to the following:

```
struct minargument{
  const uint32_t* matrix;
  ssize_t tid;
  long long results;
};

static void *minworker(void *arg){
  struct minargument *argument = (struct minargument *)arg;

  const ssize_t start = argument -> tid * CHUNK;
  const ssize_t end = argument -> tid == THREADS - 1 ? g_elements :     (argument -> tid + 1) * CHUNK;

  long long result = argument -> matrix[0];

  for(ssize_t i = start; i < end; i++){
    for(ssize_t x = 0; x < g_elements; x++){
      if(result > argument->matrix[i]){
        result = argument->matrix[i];
      }    
    }
  }

  argument -> results = result;

  return NULL;


}


uint32_t get_minimum(const uint32_t* matrix) {

    struct minargument *args = malloc(sizeof(struct minargument) * THREADS);

    long long min = 0;


    for(ssize_t i = 0; i < THREADS; i++){
      args[i] = (struct minargument){
        .matrix = matrix,
        .tid = i,
        .results = min,
      };
    }

    pthread_t thread_ids[THREADS];

    for(ssize_t i =0; i < THREADS; i++){
      if(pthread_create(thread_ids + i, NULL, minworker, args + i) != 0){
        perror("pthread_create failed");
        return 1;
      }
    }

    for (ssize_t i = 0; i < THREADS; i++){
      if(pthread_join(thread_ids[i], NULL) != 0){
        perror("pthread_join failed");
        return 1;
      }
    }
    for(ssize_t i =0; i < THREADS; i++){
      min = args[i].results;
    }


    free(args);


    return min;
}
```

However this seems to be slower than the first function.
Am I correct in using threads to make the first function run faster? And if so, how do I modify the second function so that it is faster than the first function?

Comment: This problem is almost certainly memory-bound. Adding more threads will only increase performance if the working-set does not fit into the cpu's private caches, and then only until the shared memory bandwidth is exhausted. Your testcase probably needs to be on the order of megabytes to benefit from multithreading.

Comment: How many elements you have in `matrix`? It depends on the data size, the value of `THREADS`, the number of cores you have etc. Notice that you are also not calculating the `min` properly at the end:  `for(ssize_t i =0; i < THREADS; i++){ min = args[i].results; }`

Comment: @EOF I've been testing against a pretty large number of elements so I think it will still benefit.
to BlueMoon: I'm testing from 20~20,000.

Could you guys explain how the last part is wrong

Comment: i believe thread priority factor also has a role to play in optimization.

Comment: @BlueMoon I'm almost certain there will be alot more tested when I submit, 20,000 is a number I've personally set so I can work on it.

I've tested using printf functions inside of minworker, it returns the correct min value however when I get to get_minimum function it only returns 0 until i use the  "for(ssize_t i =0; i < THREADS; i++){
      min = args[i].results;
    }"

Comment: Neither of you thought to tell him how to fix it.

Comment: @blue,weston sorry this is my first time using threading so I'm a bit confused. Doesn't for-looping over the number of threads mean that I will be iterating through all the threads?

Comment: 20,000 `long long int`s on most platforms are `~160 kB`. A typical x86 has `~256 kB` of private L2 cache. Unless the second thread is scheduled on another hyperthread on the same physical core, your testcase is at least an order of magnitude too small.

Comment: @BlueMoon fair enough! Maybe you added as an amend to the first comment, cause I don't remember it.

Comment: @LawfulEvil I think they know how to do this problem. It's just an oversight.

Comment: The only way to figure it out is to measure it. Try with different number of threads and various data sizes. No one can tell you definite answer if at all the multi-threaded version will improve performance without knowing the details. Your code looks OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having more threads than cores available to run them on is always going to be slower than a single thread due to the overhead of creating them, scheduling them and waiting for them all to finish.

The example you provide is unlikely to benefit from any optimisation beyond that which the compiler will do for you, as it is a short and simple operation.  If you were doing something more complicated on a multi-core system, such as multiplying two huge matrices, of running a correlation algorithm on high speed real-time data then multi-threading may be the solution.

A more abstract answer to your question is another question: do you really need to be optimising it at all?  Unless you know for a fact that there *are* performance issues, then *your* time would be better spent adding more functionality to your program than fixing a problem that doesn't really exist.

**Edit - Comparison**

I just ran (a representative version of) the OP's code on a 16 bit ARM microcontroller running with a 40 MHz instruction clock.  Code compiled using GCC with no optimisation.

Finding the minimum of 20,000 32 bit integers took a little over 25 milliseonds.

With a 40 kByte page size (to hold half of a 20,000 array of 4 byte values) with threads running on different cores of a dual Intel 5150 processor clocked at 2.67 GHz, it takes nearly 50 ms just to do the context switch and paging operation!

A simple, single-threaded microcontroller implementation takes half as long in real time terms as a multi-threaded desktop implementation.

Comment: It's entirely possible to improve performance of a linear search by multithreading, provided the working set is large enough.

Comment: @EOF Yes, providing you have more than one core to run the threads on.  Otherwise, threads are only useful to schedule some processes as background tasks whilst other, more time-critical threads run until the result is available and required.  If the sample set is large enough and you have the available processing resources then it could improve the performce.  Otherwise it will have the opposite effect, as observed by the OP.

Comment: You may want to rethink optimization, especially if this is part of your job. Will this code run on arrays of hundreds of millions of elements?  Will it run on smaller arrays thousands of times in a single execution?  Is this a realtime application in the sense that a user will be staring at the screen for 20 minutes if you do not "fix" it?  Will it run in batch?  Is it part of some much larger app that somebody will start and then go eat lunch?  Consider first optimizing something else, like I/O.   Shaving 10ms off  runtime is fun, not always needful.

Comment: @jimmcnamara Was that comment to me? I work in embedded software, where shaving one or two instructions off an ISR can make the difference between a good product and a useless one.  For complex signal processing, delegating algorithms to a DSP co-processor can be essential.  In the OP's case, I'd tend to keep track of the minimum value while the array is being populated.  Your last sentence is bang on the money!